# ASP.NET MVC Implementing analytics in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have this controller

```
public ActionResult Download(Guid? codice)
        {
            if (codice == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            string _pathfile = "path-to-file";

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_pathfile);
                return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, _nome);

        }
```

In google results many link point to this controller (eg: http://example.org/Download?codice=...)

My question is: how i can track this link in Analytics without Razor page?

Since i dont have a Razor i can't use Google Tag Manager or javascript to send information to google, so i have to write my own table in sql and store there my data?

Comment: Your controller contains the code for download a file.

Comment: I know this, my question is how i can track this download in analitycs, if is possible. Also if google's results points directly to pdf file maybe is impossible to track it (eg http://example.org/file.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA Tracking is not done in the controller.
By adding a click event on the link that leads to your file you can track the downloads.

For direct link downloading you'll have to add some kind of view to this because you have to fire javascript.

EDIT: I did some searching this morning , this is the correct way of doing this :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

Example of a simple pageview, i just tested it and it works :

```
HTTP METHOD : POST
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=555&t=pageview&dh=xxxxx.net&dp=/home&dt=Homepage
```

Offcourse fill in the correct UA id & website domain

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: @maurox enough info?